# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to change my class name my page scroll 400 from top of feature-animate div but i am getting this error.

please see this link for my code

https://jsbin.com/zafove/edit?html,js,output

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined error

```
 if(wScroll > $('.feature-animate').offset().top - 400 ){
            $('.feature-animate').each(function(j){
                setTimeout(function(){
                $('.feature-animate').eq(j).addClass('isShowing');
                },100 * (i+1));
```

Comment: before this line, can you print `console.log($('.feature-animate'))` in your code and tell me what it is printing?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: is this code invoked after document.ready event? Has your DOM already loaded before invoking this code?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that jquery does not find your html node with class `.feature-animate`. First and most probable reason: You have a typo in your html code. Make sure it looks like this:

```
<div class="feature-animate">...your other html code </div>
```

Then it should work.

By the way: If you have multiple div containers with the same class name, `$('.feature-animate').offset().top` will get the `top` value of the first element with that class in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the element with the `feature-animate` class has been initialized *before* the javascript is run. A great way to do this is to put it inside a `$(document).ready()` tag.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not able to find "feature-animate" element because in html its written as per following.

```
    <div classs="row feature-animate">
```

(please note 3 's' in 'classs' )

It should be as per following:

```
    <div class="row feature-animate">
```

(remove extra 's' and make it 'class')